# K6 InfluxDB + Grafana Docker : What does "git submodule update --init" mean

Tags: git, k6

I am using K6 for Load Testing.

I have cloned the K6, Grafana, InfluxDB docker-compose set up from here:

https://github.com/loadimpact/k6

The instructions for using the Docker are at the bottom of this page (https://k6.io/docs/results-visualization/influxdb-+-grafana) as shown here:

```
git clone 'https://github.com/loadimpact/k6'
cd k6
git submodule update --init
```

What does the last line mean? (git submodule update --init). I can't see it doing anything.

Also is this a one off action that is only required the first time you clone this solution?

I am going to add my own tests to the cloned solution, delete the existing .git folder,run git init and then check it into my own new repository.

When other people clone my new repository will they have to run the 'git submodule update --init' command after cloning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line tells `git` to update/get/pull submodules. This is required ... because git just doesn't pull them on its own so if you want to have access to them you need to run this command.

k6 did, long time ago(3 years I think), use submodules and apparently this has never been fixed in the documentation. I can't even tell you what the submodules were containing that would've been needed for this - but it is no longer needed.

I have made a [PR](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6-docs/pull/88) to drop it.